# ENVISAT ASAR .N1 file is not being opened by ERDAS IMAGINE 2011

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, digital-image-processing, erdas-imagine

I am not able to open ENVISAT ASAR .N1 file in ERDAS IMAGINE 2011. The software has direct read option for files of this format. Whenever I try to open the file, software closes automatically giving an error message. Can anyone point out the problem and suggest solutions.